# MS Excel: List all cell values that meet a certain criteria

Tags: excel, function

I have a few worksheets with transaction numbers that refer to each other. I need a formula that lists, for each transaction, which other transactions relate to it. Each transaction number has a four-letter code (for instance EXPE for expenses, TRAV for travel, etc.) and then a three-digit number. This is the transaction identifier, and each transaction has a unique identifier, ex. EXPE-001, TRAV-010, etc. Each transaction can be connected to other transactions. So, for instance, if a certain expense is related to a certain travel, EXPE-001 could be connected to TRAV-010.

My data is set up like the tables below. The Related Transactions column is where I would list all the transactions that a specific transaction is related to, and the Other Transaction #s column is where Excel would enter all the other transactions where this specific one is related. The cells in the Other Transaction #s column is what I need Excel to autopopulate for me.

In the Expenses worksheet,

```
Trans. #   Date         Cost    Related Transactions   Other Transaction #s
EXPE-001   2016-07-10   $1.12   TRAV-010               ____, ____, ____
EXPE-002   2016-07-10   $18.41  TRAV-010               ____, ____, ____
EXPE-003   2016-07-10   $7.80   TRAV-010               ____, ____, ____
```

In the Travel worksheet,

```
Trans. #   Date         Cost    Related Transactions   Other Transaction #s
TRAV-001   2016-07-10   $180.01 EXPE-001, EXPE-002     ____, ____, ____
TRAV-002   2016-07-10   $31.16  EXPE-002, EXPE-003     ____, ____, ____
TRAV-003   2016-07-10   $190.49 EXPE-003               ____, ____, ____
```

As you can see, each transaction can be referred to in any number of other transactions, and each transaction can also refer to any number of other transactions. It's like a big web. What makes this more confusing is that the data in Trans. # is actually stored as a number, ex. 1, 2, 3, and only displayed by its code and the appropriate number of leading 0s.

I know how to take the number, add the transaction code, and pad it with zeroes. I use `TEXT` (for instance, `"*EXPE-"&TEXT(A12, "000"&"*"` with asterisk wildcards so that the substring can appear anywhere in the cell).

Anyway, I've been playing with the `MATCH` function to grab the row number of a specific string in a range of rows. And I've been playing with the `INDEX`, `IF`, `SMALL` functions too. But this is so confusing, partly because I think so many functions are involved, as well as trying to make this an array function (by hitting CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER) so that Excel lists across multiple rows in multiple ranges. So far my attempts have all gotten me a #REF!, a #N/A, a #VALUE, or a straight-out error message from Excel. For a table with only 6 transactions in it, I'd use the row range of 3-8 (there are two rows of headers). In various pieces, I've got the following that all don't work or do only a fraction of the job:

```
=INDEX(A3:A8, SMALL(IF((INDEX(A3:A8, , $C$3, 1)="EXPE" & TEXT($A$3, "000")), ROW(A3:A8), ""), ROWS(A19:$A$19)), , 1)
=MATCH(A8, A3:A8)
=INDEX(A3:P37, MATCH(A8, A3:A37))
```

But I'm absolutely lost on this. Seems I can't even get step 1 to work. I haven't even figured out how to do this over one worksheet let alone multiple ones. Does anybody have any idea how to solve this insane formula?

Comment: Well, I cobbled some solutions together from different sources: here (thanks, Bruce!), online, my own testing and grunting and sweating and pleading with Excel, and came up with this: `="EXPE-"&TEXT(INDEX(credits_transactionnumbers, SMALL(IF("EXPE-"&TEXT(A29,"000")=L3:L37, ROW(L3:L37)-MIN(ROW(L3:L37))+1, ""), ROW(A1))),"000")` which, if I put in different cells and increase A1 each time (A2, A3, ...) will give me the coordinates. The only thing i need now is to be able to put these values in a long, comma-separated string in one single cell, and to stop before #NUM!. More headway!

Answer (score 0):

You're saying the Trans. # column is formatted to display 1, 2, 3 as TRAV-001, TRAV-002, TRAV-003 respectively?  If so, MATCH will only match the row for 1, 2, 3.

I would either enter the data as TRAV-001...or add another column, enter the 1 and have another column correctly format the Transaction number (=EXPE-"&TEXT(A12, "000"&"*").  Or, just match 1, 2, 5, etc.

Comment: Better yet...get rid of the cell formatting in Trans. #.  Instead, enter a formula in that column.  Since expenses always involve Costs, make the Trans. # column dependent on the Cost column.

Comment: For example, =IF($C2="","","EXPE-"&TEXT(ROW($C2)-1,"000"))

Comment: ...and, if your sheet names are the same as your types of transactions (EXPE, TRAV, TIPS, etc), you could further automate your formula to include the type of transaction.

Comment: For example, =IF($C2="","",MID(CELL("filename",$A$1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",$A$1),1)+1,10)&"-"&TEXT(ROW($C2)-1,"000"))

Comment: For the Other Transaction #s column, which I assumed is Column E, enter array formula: `=IF(COUNTIF($D$1:$D$100,"*"&$A2&"*")<(COLUMN()-4),"",INDIRECT(ADDRESS(SMALL(IF(ISERR(IF(SEARCH("*"&$A2&"*",$D$1:$D$100,1),ROW($D$1:$D$100),"")),"",ROW($D$1:$D$100)),COLUMN()-4),1)))`

Comment: Oops...you may want to embed my Other Transactions formula within an IF function:  =IF($A2="","",MyFormulaHere)

Comment: Heheh. I will, @Bruce. I'll give this a shot. In the meantime, I made some headway...I think anyway. I've got `=INDEX(MATCH("*EXPE-"&TEXT(A29,"000")&"*",L3:L37,0),1)`. So far this finds the first instance (giving me the number of rows from the beginning of the range). I just need to work this in to an array formula. I'm trying out the SMALL function with it as well, which correctly gives me the Kth smallest value. It's only a matter of time until I work that into giving me coordinates and then into an array that gives me the next and then the next, etc. Hope I'm on the right track!

Comment: But I'm going to pop your code into my spreadsheet first chance I get, @Bruce, and I'll let you know.

Comment: Out of my 4 comments, I'd put my 2nd formula into column A.  Then I'd put my 4th formula in Column E (replacing MyFormulaHere of course).  Glad to help.